# How do I get NDepend to do a baseline comparison on TeamCity?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, ndepend

I've got NDepend running on TeamCity.  I want to use the baseline feature so that it only reports on violations introduced since the baseline.

On my local machine, I can store the results in a baseline folder and everything is fine.  But on TeamCity, this baseline folder doesn't exist and will dissapear on each build.

One solution is to check-in my baseline into source control so that it's available when TeamCity does the build.  Then, update this baseline locally and re-check-in.  That's not ideal though, as it'll mean a lot of 'churn' in our version control system.

What's the best way to get 'Recent violations only' working on TeamCity?

Comment: Before mid June 2015 we will release a new version that will come with an advanced TeamCity plugin that will support baseline and code coverage as well.
We will then answer your StakOverflow question ok?

Comment: Btw, see the upcoming NDepend TeamCity Plugin Walk Through video. Baseline explanations is at the end at 7:30, feedbacks are welcome. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBfWQekLQZI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NDepend v6](http://www.ndepend.com/ndepend-v6) has just been released with built-in support for TeamCity v8 and v9.

The plugin has special support for baseline comparison in TeamCity.

See Getting Started and Walkthrough videos [here](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/teamcity-integration-ndepend).